# Flag-Posts Privilege documentation needs updating

Tags: support, flags, help-center, documentation

According to https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts users should be able to flag a question for 6 different reasons as soon as they have 50 rep.

However not all reasons appear on all sites.  Are there further functions that determine which question flags are shown?  For example, I can't find the "very low quality" flag anywhere.  And on Sound I only see "other", where anyone with 15 rep should be able to at least see "spam" and "offensive" as well.

**Update:** Some of the confusion results from checking flags on one's own questions, which one cannot flag for "spam" or "offensive" content.

Perhaps the only serious point not documented is that the "very low quality" flag is only available on questions with a negative vote tally.

Comment: The Very Low Quality flag only shows up for posts with a negative score.

Comment: Note that the 50-rep requirement only applies to flag reason #4 and its sub-reasons. Which question were you looking at on Sound and only saw "other"?

Comment: Oops: On the Sound site I happened to only check flags for questions I had asked.  When I look at questions asked by others I get the usual three flag options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dialog is context-sensitive; all options exist, but not all are available at all times.

I've added a note about the score requirement for Very Low Quality though.